# How would you architect a simple cascading style sheet object?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, inheritance, css, dynamic-inheritance

How would you architect a simple cascading stylesheet like inheritance object?

For example, I have Apple that extends Fruit.

```
class Fruit {

    constructor() {
       this.total = 10;
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

On Fruit there is a property named total with a value of 10. The apple instance can change the property value to anything else. But if I delete the property value somehow I want it to return to the original subclass value.

```
var apple = new Apple();
log(apple.total); // 10

apple.total = 200;
log(apple.total); // 200

delete apple.total;
log(apple.total); // 10
```

I'm using ES6 for this project but I can probably figure out the syntax with the a  design pattern.

This may or may not be Cascading Style Sheets.

Comment: The way that best serves the specific application I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this kind of behavior, you need, generally speaking, composition and [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)–style forwarding. However, since inheritance in JavaScript is prototype-based (see [this](https://www.debuggr.io/js-prototype-in-depth/) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)), you already have this built in. A property is resolved by first looking for it on the object itself<sup>1</sup>; if it's not there, the search continues up the inheritance chain (of prototypes), and each prototype is examined for the property.

The line `this.total = 30` actually creates an own<sup>1</sup> property on the Apple instance.
But, you only need to make a small change:

```js
class Fruit {    
    constructor() {
    } 
}

Fruit.prototype.total = 10       // <---- HERE

class Apple extends Fruit {
    constructor() {             
        super();
    } 
}

var apple = new Apple(); 
console.log(apple.total); // 10

apple.total = 200; 
console.log(apple.total); // 200

delete apple.total; 
console.log(apple.total); // 10
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Properties on the object itself are known as "own properties" (as in "object's own properties").

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - yeah! Actually, there's *more* than that. The variable itself refers to your instance, but behind the scenes, there's another object that stores the methods (plays the role of the Apple class, essentially), and than that object has its prototype set to an object that stores Fruit's methods, and it itself refers in turn to the Object.prototype, that stores the methods of Object and represents the Object base class (these prototypes are shared among instances according to the type hierarchy).

Comment: You can access the prototype in a browser console using `__proto__`, but note that using `Object.getPrototypeOf` is the recommended way (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)).

Comment: (Noticed your comment, but had to do something else before answering - it seems that you've deleted it in the meantime? I'll leave my comments anyway, if it helps clarify things.)

Comment: I didn't want to go too in depth so I deleted it but since you answered it the original comment was IIRC, "When one class extends another is there then two instances in memory, the base class and then class that extends it."